# Supremum of upper semicontinuous (usc) functions

Tags: functional-analysis

The supremum of finitely many usc functions is usc. I'm wondering when/if the supremum of infinitely many bounded usc functions could be usc? Any hint, examples, or counterexamples?

Comment: A few more details: I'm thinking of a set of uncountably infinite functions. Maybe it helps to think in terms of l.s.c. functions [a function f is u.s.c iff -f is l.s.c.]

So f is l.s.c. iff the epigraph (set of points on or above the graph) of f is a closed set

The epigraph of a function which is the minimum of a given set of functions is a union of the epigraphs of the given functions.

Comment: But the union of an infinite number of closed sets may not be closed, which is probably the issue... 
[think of R^n being a union of its points (closed sets) or a countably infinite number of expanding closed boxes.].

In order to guarantee that the union of the closed sets is closed, maybe one could make an assumption that the collection of the closed sets is locally finite, i.e., any point in the space these sets reside in has a neighborhood that intersects only finitely many of those closed sets.